# Convert table format - long to wide - table with two columns - Pandas / Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a table like this

```
Program     Seg     Percent
N           A       1%
N           B       13%
N           C       4%
Y           A       6%
Y           B       5%
Y           C       8%
```

Would like to convert it to:

```
Seg        A           A          B           B           C           C
Program    N           Y          N           Y           N           Y
Percent    1%          6%         13%         5%          4%          8%
```

Whether seg or program appear as title of columns or row index is not really important.
Just want it to be selectable in some way in python.

Note that simply transposing is not what I'm looking for. I need to have 'Seg' as the first variable, then 'Program'.

Looking for the solution in both Pandas and possibly Excel.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create subset with expected order, sort by both columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = df[['Seg','Program','Percent']].sort_values(['Seg','Program']).T
print (df)
          0   3    1   4   2   5
Seg       A   A    B   B   C   C
Program   N   Y    N   Y   N   Y
Percent  1%  6%  13%  5%  4%  8%
```

Solution with `MulitIndex` (repeated values are not displayed only):

```
df = df.set_index(['Seg','Program'])[['Percent']].sort_index().T
print (df)
Seg       A        B       C    
Program   N   Y    N   Y   N   Y
Percent  1%  6%  13%  5%  4%  8%
```